# Snapping / aligning text to the top center of a specific face normal using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I snap and align a string of text to the top center of a specific face using **geometry nodes**.  I'm using Blender 3.0.1

Node setup below

[image: img1]

**Red Arrow** is where I want the text to be

**Note: I know I can just move the text manually but the goal is to learn / do this using GN.**

[image: img2]

Comment: How do you want to specify which exactly face should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way:

[image]

It goes:

- The input mesh has vertex normals; points don't. So capture the *Normal* field on points. It's a field, so will be interpolated when called on, to yield face normals.
- Center up the text to its Pivot Point using the *String* settings
- Select the point for instancing, by Index
- Align the instance's Z to the face normal, in the *Instance to Points* node.

[image]